# Spring Data Hibernate commit not saved to db

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, tomcat9

We have a file parsing job which read the file line be line and creates records. The file is read from S3. After processing, the files are moved to processed bucket.

In this one rare occurrence, the logs say that the files are read and created records are saved successfully within a minute. However, no data is not found for this file. On debugging this, i found below exception trace and it was thrown after 30 mins suggesting it was trying to get connection for 30 mins. Also, we had oracle db issue at the same time and we had to restart the oracle server.

sample log suggesting no exception `LOG.info(" Saved the recordCount={} for fileName={} ", savedRecords.size(), dataFileName);`

```
2023-12-09 13:32:59.533 +0000 [Tomcat JDBC Pool Cleaner[1393931310:1702120802661]] [WARN] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool    - Connection has been abandoned PooledConnection[oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@1ef84e3b]:java.lang.Exception
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getThreadDump(ConnectionPool.java:1222)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:841)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:678)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:197)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:133)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:108)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:138)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:276)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:284)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:246)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:164)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:421)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:595)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:382)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
```

fileRepository `@Repository public interface FileJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<File, Long>`

RecordRepository `public interface RecordJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Record, Long>`

I do understand that this happened due to oracle database issue. However, I want to understand why there was no exception thrown and why there was no rollback. The fileProcessing method is transactional. If the connection was not available, some form of exception should have been thrown. Any insight on why it did not throw any exception and what we can do in future to prevent such issues?